# How to define nearest neighbor search such that it can be optimized using stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, stochastic-gradient-descent

Assume that there is a reference two-dimensional array `ref` and a given vector `x`. I would like to return the closest vector to `x` from `ref`, such that the operation is differentiable.

The pseudo-code I currently have, which is not differentiable, is like this:

1. Find the distance between `x` and all elements of `ref`
2. Find the index that has the minimum distance
3. Return `ref[index]`

Step 2. of this pseudo-code is the part that makes it non-differentiable.

Can I define this problem in a different way, such that it can be optimized using SGD?

Comment: you can use exponential function. e^D

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: *you can't* and it wouldn't make any sense. To find the index with the shortest distance you need to conduct simple line search, i.e. go through all the examples and find out the one with the smallest distance. There is nothing to optimize here, no function to minimize, or maximize, you just need to check all the examples.

Comment: That's exactly why I'm confused. There's a NIPS 2017 paper that has something similar to nearest neighbor search in Eq. 2, but optimizes the objective using SGD. You can find the paper here: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7157-multiscale-quantization-for-fast-similarity-search.pdf

Comment: @Mahdi I don't have time right now to read the paper carefully, but the keyword you should notice in the paper is the **approximate** nearest neighbors. They use some kind of approximation, so for the details on "how" did they approximate it you should refer to the paper.